# Type mismatch when trying to convert an Observable to a Signal in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-signals

I am trying to convert an `Observable` into a `Signal` to be returned from the `login` function.

```js
login(username: string, password: string): Signal<LoginResponse> {
  const sourceObservable: Observable<LoginResponse> =
    this.http.post<LoginResponse>(this.apiUrl + '/login', {username, password})

  let lrp: LoginResponse = LoginResponse.withStatus(ResponseStatus.PENDING)

  return toSignal<LoginResponse>(sourceObservable, {requireSync: true, initialValue: lrp,}
  )
}
```

In the return statement I use `toSignal()` that takes a `ToSignalOptions` object with `requireSync` set to true, and an initial value. However the compiler is complaining at me that there are no overload matches, because it is expecting an `initialValue` of type undefined, whereas I am providing a type of `LoginResponse`. It *should* be LoginResponse, but the analyser does not like that.

Have I done something wrong I am overlooking?

Here's a shot of the error the IDE is displaying.
[image: Error as displayed by the IDE]

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `requireSync` from the `ToSignalOptions`

`initialValue` is allowed only when `requireSync` is falsy

Comment: Thank you for your response. The way I read the documentation, if I remove `requireSync` then my return type must be `<T | undefined>` (emphasis on undefined), but I was wanting to avoid that and have the return type just be `<T>`. Additionally I cannot find any documentation stating that requireSync must be false to use initial value. That seems unintuitive to me. Would you have any sources on that? I'd be interested to read about it.

Comment: I should also add that I did actually attempt removing `requireSync` I still got function signature mismatch errors (three of them) https://i.imgur.com/xvdLr5R.png

Comment: hi @Stephen, it was my understanding that `requireSync: true` and truthy `initialValue` will not be used together.. sorry, I dont have any other sources apart from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

toSignal() requires injection context, we can't call it wherever we want.
If you want to use it like this, provide an injector in params:

```
class SomeService {
  private readonly http = inject(HttpClient);
  private readonly apiUrl = 'https://api.example.com';
  private readonly injector = inject(Injector);

  login(username: string, password: string): Signal<LoginResponse> {
    const sourceObservable = this.http.post<LoginResponse>(
      this.apiUrl + '/login',
      { username, password }
    );

    const lrp: LoginResponse = LoginResponse.withStatus(ResponseStatus.PENDING);

    return toSignal<LoginResponse>(sourceObservable, {
      injector: this.injector,
      initialValue: lrp,
    });
  }
}
```